# How SSTable stores its triplets to the file system?

Tags: bigtable, gfs, nosql

How exactly SSTable stores its string string keys [row, column, timestamp] triples to the file system, 
are all triplets in the same directory, in different directories, in the same file or in some other way?
The question is specifically about the file/directory structure of SSTable , which is part of BigTable and based on GFS. More specifically about the actual names of the files that store that triplets and their directory structure.

It seems that an example of actual storing and retrieving such key value triplets would demystify the  concept.

Ideally a nice diagram or multiple diagrams would make it much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

"[SSTable and Log Structured Storage: LevelDB](https://www.igvita.com/2012/02/06/sstable-and-log-structured-storage-leveldb/)" by Ilya Grigorik, an engineer at Google, describes the SSTable structure and includes several diagrams.

Also, [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) is an open source project by Google which includes an implementation of SSTables in [`table.h`](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/include/leveldb/table.h) and [`table.cc`](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/table/table.cc).